# Creating database yields error "Failed to get enough keypoints from target image."

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore

#### The Problem

Whenever I try to create a database with my images, it results in the error `Failed to get enough keypoints from target image.` and displays the quality of each image as `ERROR/100`. Here are my images:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qhZVy-2wfoDg5gVEH23ER4k1alVxsKd3

To create these, I first made a SVG copy using google drawings (that you can see in the `SVGs` folder), and then I used the following `imagemagick` command:

`magick mogrify -units pixelsperinch -density 600 -quality 100 -format jpg *.svg`

Here is a gif of what happens when I try to create the database:

#### Creating a database

[image: Creating a database]

#### My specs

I am running Unity 2019.1.5f1 (Personal & Free Edition) & ARCore 1.13 (Latest version as of now) on a Windows 10 computer from Lenovo.

#### EDIT

Just to clarify, my problem isn't with `imagemagick`. My problem is that ARCore's database can't get the `Quality` of the images. The only reason I included `imagemagick` was that it might have something to do with the way it parsed the images.

#### EDIT 2

I just tried it, and it looks like the problem was that it was too plain of an image. When I tried it with a different one, it worked the first time.

Thanks,

Ayush

Comment: Does it fail if you use just `magick -units pixelsperinch -density 600 input.svg -quality 100 output.jpg`? What SVG renderer are you using: Imagemagick's MSVG/XML, RSVG delegate or Inkscape?

Comment: Sorry if it was a bit confusing - my problem is not with `imagemagick`, just with ARCore itself... I only included the `imagemagick` part because I thought that it had created an image that couldn't be parsed by ARCore's Database...

Answer (score 0):

I have been a similar problem. It seems, that my images were a bit too similar for unity to make references for tracking. I do not know how unity works this matter, but i guess you could figure that out with documentation.
Anywhowho, my solution was to make different QRs, just to make different images.
Maybe is a bit loo late, but try very different images and see if the problem is solved.

best of luck :)
J